# Ubuntu Server 12.04 Won't Boot After Install

Tags: boot, server, system-installation

The installation of Ubuntu Server 12.04 on my PC was finished smoothly but when I try to boot it, the following message appears:

```
Reboot and select proper boot device...
```

This is the output after I run a boot info:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/6914342/

And after running the boot info script

```
                      Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       linux_raid_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       linux_raid_member
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1 1,953,525,167 1,953,525,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048     7,813,119     7,811,072 RAID partition (Linux)
/dev/sda2       7,813,120 1,953,523,711 1,945,710,592 EFI System partition

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________

Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1                   1 1,953,525,167 1,953,525,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdb1           2,048     7,813,119     7,811,072 RAID partition (Linux)
/dev/sdb2       7,813,120 1,953,523,711 1,945,710,592 EFI System partition

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/loop0                                              squashfs   
/dev/sda1        8bcf74b5-7cbd-25a9-31c5-537344fcd5c0   linux_raid_member server:0
/dev/sda2        80d5941c-88e4-4ffc-bdf4-42cf53dbfee8   ext4       
/dev/sdb1        8bcf74b5-7cbd-25a9-31c5-537344fcd5c0   linux_raid_member server:0
/dev/sdb2        677c215a-c736-44e6-a7f3-3026764fc715   ext4       
/dev/sr0                                                iso9660    Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS i386

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/loop0       /rofs                    squashfs   (ro,noatime)
/dev/sr0         /cdrom                   iso9660    (ro,noatime)
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

From the boot-repair log it was clearly shown that you didn't install Ubuntu server on Your HDD.

So try to install it again on any one of the ext4 partition.

Comment: Can I ask how did that happen? I carefully followed what was instructed on the Ubuntu 12.04 Server Installation Guide site. (https://help.ubuntu.com/12.04/serverguide/advanced-installation.html) I even watched some Youtube instruction videos.

How do I install it again on the ext4 installation?

Comment: please try the installation again.